# Having trouble getting a curl command to work in R

Tags: r, curl

I have a working curl command:

```
curl -d '{"query":"query {\n    accountBalances (first: 5) {\n        nodes {\n            id\n            accountId\n            tokenId\n            total\n        }\n    }\n    accounts (first: 5) {\n        nodes {\n            id\n            address\n            mark\n        }\n    }\n}","variables":null}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://api.subquery.network/sq/AcalaNetwork/karura-tokens
```

I am trying to make it work in R.  For example

```
library(httr)
baseurl <- 'https://api.subquery.network/sq/AcalaNetwork/karura-tokens'
body <- '{"query":"query {\n    accountBalances (first: 5) {\n        nodes {\n            id\n            accountId\n            tokenId\n            total\n        }\n    }\n    accounts (first: 5) {\n        nodes {\n            id\n            address\n            mark\n        }\n    }\n}","variables":null}'
POST(url = 'https://api.subquery.network/sq/AcalaNetwork/karura-tokens',
     body  = 'query {\n    accountBalances (first: 5) {\n        nodes {\n            id\n            accountId\n            tokenId\n            total\n        }\n    }\n    accounts (first: 5) {\n        nodes {\n            id\n            address\n            mark\n        }\n    }',
     add_headers('Content-Type: application/json'))
```

or this

```
library(RCurl)
postForm(baseurl,
         data = body,
         .opts = list(httpheader = c('Content-Type' = 'application/json', Accept = 'application/json')))
```

Can anyone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting? When I rune the code you provided I et "SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired" -- so that's a problem with the server configuration, not the R code. How can we test the code to verify it works?

Comment: I probably should have shown the error returned, but it is not very helpful, just a 400 with no additional comments: ```response [https://api.subquery.network/sq/AcalaNetwork/karura-tokens]
  Date: 2022-04-22 12:59
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Size: 68 B ```. As for testing, the curl statement at the top can be pasted into any terminal to see what output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

A more appropriate translation would be be

```
POST(url = baseurl,
     body  = list(
       query = 'query {\n    accountBalances (first: 5) {\n        nodes {\n            id\n            accountId\n            tokenId\n            total\n        }\n    }\n    accounts (first: 5) {\n        nodes {\n            id\n            address\n            mark\n        }\n    }',
       variables = NA
     ),
     encode = 'json')
```

Here we pass a list for the values you want to submit and set the encoding type to `json` to POST will do the encoding for us.

Comment: This format provided some additional error messages, but I still could not get it to work: ```Response [https://api.subquery.network/sq/AcalaNetwork/karura-tokens]
  Date: 2022-04-22 13:02
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 1.39 kB
{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error: Expected Name, found <EOF>.","extensions":{"code":"GRAPHQL_PARSE_FAILED","exception":{"stacktrace":["GraphQLError: Syn...
```

Comment: Without seeing the full error message it's hard to say what's happening. When i use the code and compare it to the CURL command at a site like https://requestbin.net where i can see the request, they look the same to me.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.  I will check out that site.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get it to work, using a library for GraphQL.

```
library(ghql)
x <- GraphqlClient$new()
url <- 'https://api.subquery.network/sq/AcalaNetwork/karura-tokens'
query <- 'query { accountBalances (first: 5) { nodes { id accountId tokenId total } } }'

method = "test"
cli <- GraphqlClient$new(url)
qry <- Query$new()
qry$query(method, query)
result <- cli$exec(qry$queries[[method]])
```

I am just annoyed that I couldn't figure how to do it with a simple POST form.